# How to insert a record with validation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2000

Master Table

```
ID Date Value

001 23-04-2009 200
001 24-04-2009 300
002 23-04-2009 250
002 24-04-2009 350
002 25-04-2009 250
....
```

Secondary Table

```
ID Date Value

    001 23-04-2009 200
    001 24-04-2009 300
    002 23-04-2009 250
    002 24-04-2009 350
    002 25-04-2009 250
    002 26-04-2009 550
    ....
```

In the master table i want to insert a data's from the secondary table (Each data's should insert from next date onwards for each id)

If i am inserting secondary table data's in to master table, master table should accept id from next date onwards...

Expected output

```
ID Date Value

001 23-04-2009 200 'old record from master table
001 24-04-2009 300 'old record from master table
002 23-04-2009 250 'old record from master table
002 24-04-2009 350 'old record from master table
002 25-04-2009 250 'old record from master table
002 26-04-2009 550 'New Record from Secondary Table
```

Below mentioned record is not inserted in the master table, because date is available for the id's in the master table

```
    001 23-04-2009 200
    001 24-04-2009 300
    002 23-04-2009 250
    002 24-04-2009 350
    002 25-04-2009 250
```

How to make a query for insert a record with validation(id and date).

Need SQL Query Help

Comment: So you want a row into the master table when a secondary row is inserted? Or to stop a insert on the secondary table when no matching master row? I understand English isn't your native language, but it isn't clear what you want just now, sorry

Comment: @gbn, This is not a English grammer site, if you are not understand, post a comments like "not clear" instead of putting blamming words...

Comment: I was trying to be polite. Now, fix your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select s.*
from 
(select id, date, value
from secondaryTable ) s ,

(
select id, max(date) as date 
from mainTable
group by id ) a

where s.id = a.id and s.date>a.date
```

this query should return the desired rows that are supposed to be inserted in main table, I have not tested the query, pardon any bugs

Comment: It is Showing Error on s, Can you check it please....

Comment: @Gopal, in the first glance, i observed comma was missing after s, can you plz try that.

Comment: I tried with comma also, It showing error as Incorrect syntax near ',',  Could You please check....

Comment: @Gopal There might be some spacing issue, if u are running query via code, try to enter spaces after comma, if problem is not solved then please post the actual query (from logs, or console) that you are trying to execute. because I executed the query with different tables and it executed without errors.

Comment: Query is "SELECT     s.*
FROM         ((SELECT     *
                         FROM         Punching_EventMaster) s,
                          (SELECT     Emp_Code, MAX(dates)
                            FROM          Punching_Attendance
                            GROUP BY Emp_Code) a)
WHERE     s.Emp_Code = a.Emp_Code AND s.dates > a.dates",  It is showing error in comma (near to s).  Please help me....

Comment: @Gopal I slept :), I observed one issue right now, although it does not match with your error description, but no harm in trying. I have edited the above answer.

Comment: Do not encourage the poor use of implicit joins.

Comment: @HLGEM Can you please explain why thats considered a poor use of implicit join ? I have been using this for a while and if its really the poor strategy, I need to change that.

Comment: Implicit joins are a sql antipattern, they were replaced almost 20 years ago with explicit joins. They are subject to accidental cross joins and they are harder for maintenance especially since the left join implicit syntax is unreliable and deprecated and you should not mix implicit and explicit joins in the same query or you might get strange results. They are harder to read and understand. I have observed that the implicit join is often used by people who don't understand joins and they don't really understand their results sets. People learning should not be exposed to this poor practice.

Comment: @HLGEM thx, will look into it in more detail. +1